# pop menu cannot show up

Tags: c#, popupmenu

```
BarButtonItem barBtnItem = new BarButtonItem();
PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu();
                                   
//popMenu.Popup += new EventHandler(popMenuPopupHandler);
//BarLinkContainerItem linkContainer = new BarLinkContainerItem();
//pagGroup.ItemLinks.Add(linkContainer);
var ddlItemList = group.MenuItems.FindAll(p => (p.MasterName != null) && (p.MasterName.Trim() == item.MasterName.Trim()));
imagePath = startPath.Trim() + "MenuIcon\\" + item.MasterIcon;
Image mastimage = ReadPicture(imagePath);
if (mastimage == null)
{
    mastimage = ReadPicture(imagePath);
}
else if (mastimage.Width >= 30)
{
    barBtnItem.LargeGlyph = mastimage;  //按钮图标--大图标
}
else
{
    barBtnItem.Glyph = mastimage;  //按钮图标 --小图标                           
}
barBtnItem.RibbonStyle = RibbonItemStyles.All;
barBtnItem.ButtonStyle = BarButtonStyle.DropDown;
barBtnItem.Caption = item.MasterName;
barBtnItem.Enabled = true;
barBtnItem.VisibleWhenVertical = true;
barBtnItem.CategoryGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
barBtnItem.Visibility = BarItemVisibility.Always;
barBtnItem.ActAsDropDown = true;
foreach (MenuItemInfo item1 in ddlItemList)
{
    popMenu.LinksPersistInfo.Add(new LinkPersistInfo(CreateBarButtonItem(item1),true));
    popMenu.ItemLinks.Add(CreateBarButtonItem(item1));
    //barBtnItem.ItemLinks[0].Visible = true;

}

//popMenu.Visible = true;
barBtnItem.DropDownControl = popMenu;
pagGroup.ItemLinks.Add(barBtnItem);
```

### [image]

the popup menu show on the form. there are several buttons under the popup menu. but when click the dropdown button can't pop up . --------------------------------------------

Comment: possible duplicate of [the popup Menu cannot show up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510600/the-popup-menu-cannot-show-up)

Comment: what you mean of duplicate

Comment: this is not a bug. only data not show up . the project work fine.

Comment: You posted the same question twice (which is prohibited). That is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ribonContrl.Items.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem[] {                                    
                                 linkContainer                                     
                                });
```

you need add the barlinkcontaineritem in the ribbon control